# Setting datetime axis bounds as half days using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

I have the following plot with datetime on the `x` axis, but I'd like to trim the start and end times to halfway through the days.

[image: plot]

The limit setting script is currently

```
ax1.set_xlim([datetime.date(2020, 9, 16), datetime.date(2020, 9, 26)])
```

Is there a way to alter the plot to trim to a non full day?

Comment: There are several chapters on [datetime formatting](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html) in the matplotlib documentation. What have you tried of those?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, all sorted now. Very new to all this!

Comment: Great to hear that you solved your problem. You are encouraged to answer your own question and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with thanks to Mr T.

Rather than the previous code, setting the limits in the plotting code, I created an object:

```
lims=[np.datetime64('2020-09-16 15:00'), np.datetime64('2020-09-25 17:00')]
```

Which was then applied to the plotting code:

```
ax1.set_xlim(lims)
```

The resultant plot looks like this:

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhjVU.png)